# Is there a way to know if an Ionic App Android user is using WebView or Chrome?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

My Adnroid app depends on some functionality that is present from some specific WebView or Chrome versions but not the same.

I can get the current version of the WebView but I am not sure if there is a way to check if the device is using WebView For Android as WevView engine or Chrome.

Can this be done.

Answer (score 0):

I think `platform` provides this functionality:

[Platform - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/platform#is-platformname-platforms-boolean)

I think the two options you would use are `cordova` for a device and `pwa` for a browser - although it wouldn't guarantee it was Chrome.

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage {
  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
     if(platform.is("cordova") {

     } else if (platform.is("pwa") {

     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also be in a cordova environment using chrome. Since an Android version ( I think 8) when the user has Chrome installed it uses it as their webview engine.